# Nunit Tests order of Execution

Tags: nunit

This might seem a sily question to those who are well versed in autonmation but I am struggling with many things. Here's one:

I am finding that the tests I created with Selenium RC in Visual Studio 2008 are getting run from NUnit in the alphabetical order of their names?

What am I missing? Is there a way to organize the order in which the tests in Nunit are run?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [NUnit Test Run Order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078658/nunit-test-run-order). Note that all of the answers there suggest that your tests should not be order-dependent. Since that question doesn't offer a solution, I suggest that you simply put a numeric order at the beginning of each of your test names, so that they alphabetically sort in the order you expect them to run.

Comment: Just curious to know why you care about the order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit test sequence when running all tests in solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823015/unit-test-sequence-when-running-all-tests-in-solution)

Comment: AH, I forgot to mention I am executing UI tests and not unit tests. So these are tests created with Selenium RC.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, your unit tests should all be able to run independently of each other so ordering should not matter.

I think it might be time to re-think how you are doing your tests.

If you just want them run in a specific order because that's how you "prefer" them to be run, then I would argue that you are throwing away precious time doing something that really isn't that important.

If you need specific things done before the tests are executed, check out the [setup and teardown](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.2.10) methods.

Comment: The problem is I am executing UI automation tests not unit tests.

Comment: I just knew that for a very specific question with a specific answer the "top" answer will be someone questioning "design" decisions of a project they haven't even seen. NUnit doesn't have to be used just for unit tests.