# How to set NUNIT TEST Case order without using SETUP attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have a separate `NUNIT Test Case` project having approx 500 test case. I want set test case execution order without using `SETUP` attribute.

I have search over google, but no success.

If anyone have idea or link, please share.

Comment: Please take a lokk at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981469/nunit-tests-order-of-execution.

Comment: @meilke it is using `setup` and `teardown`. But my question is different

Comment: Why is the order of your tests important for you? It should not make any difference in the results.

Comment: because those are dependent to each other.